# Alias in select doesn' work in group by

Tags: jpa, select, jpql

I have the following jpa/jpql query:

```
select doiPoolName, (case when strpos(errormessage, 'Error exporting DOI') > 0 then 'Error exporting DOI' else errormessage end ) as errormes, count(*)
from DoiError doiError
where errortime >= to_timestamp('2015-01-06 10:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
group by doiPoolName, errormes
order by errormes asc
```

which will be translated in SQL in the following form:

```
select
  doierror0_.doiPoolName as col_0_0_,
  case
    when strpos(errormessage, 'Error exporting DOI')>0 then 'Error exporting DOI' else errormessage
  end as col_1_0_,
  count(*) as col_2_0_
from
  ERROR doierror0_
where
  errortime>=to_timestamp(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
group by
  doierror0_.doiPoolName ,
  errormes
order by
  col_1_0_ asc
```

By executing the query, I get the following error:

> "ERROR: column "errormes" does not exist"

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the *group by* as instead of *col_1_0_* there is *errormes* which means that there it is not correctly "translated"...

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try moving the GROUP BY to an outer query, it will do the trick. But I don't know JPA, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @Miguel Roxo mmm, what do you mean? I'm not so good in sql...

Comment: Doing something like `SELECT doiPoolname, errormes, COUNT(*) FROM ( <your_query_without_the_group_by_or_count> ) q GROUP BY doiPoolName, errormes ORDER BY erromes asc`